# Would Installing a latest API on Android SDK give me the functionalities of previous APIs or I would have to install the previous ones too?

Tags: android, api

I think when they release a new API it also includes the functionalities of the previous APIs. So if I'm installing APIs on SDK manager, then installing API 21 would give me the functionalities of API 20,19,18 and older? Or I would have to install each individual API that are older than API 21?

Answer (score 1):

Its giving all backwards functionalities, but if you want to build an app with older api as target api you will need older sdk. Consider that app built ie: for api 22 will run on api 16 if your min sdk in project is set to handle it.

Consequence of it that app built with newer sdk will use ie. newer ui controls look. (IMHO good example is look of EditText, compare material and holo version). So app built with api22 sdk will have material like effects on all devices and app built with api 16 will have holo like effects on all (even on lollipop devices).

For backwards compatibility of new features use `Support Library', you should now that sometimes it is not perfect so you can use 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

Installing new API SDK will basically give you all the functionalities you might need while developing your application. For backwards compatibility you might use [Support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Comment: This answer doesn't really say much.  A good answer would explain the backward compatibility philosophy of the Android SDK and how it affects the OP.